# Опасения по поводу размера Remote Catalog'а, создаваемого Addressable Asset System

Tags: unity3d

Меня волнует следующее. Предствьте, что вы занимаетесь игрой, где есть огромный набор шмота, который подгружается, как DLC. Говоря огромный, я имею в виду несколько тысяч ассетов, которые могут еще и обновляться периодически.

Я опасаюсь того, что клиентам постоянно придется качать довольно увесистый json, тот самый remote catalog, который создает Addressable Asset System, как маппинг ассетов к их физическому местонахождению.

Насколько я понимаю, сейчас сделано так, что подразумевается только один remote catalog. В их [workflow здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.1/manual/AddressableAssetsDevelopmentCycle.html?_ga=2.254154635.245230651.1580028923-1943554546.1539242327#content-update-workflow) написано, что, при обновлении контента, надо пересоздавать catalog. А как быть, если этот каталог будет получаться по несколько десятков Mb? Кто-нибудь имел с этим дело? Хотел выяснить этот вопрос перед тем, как внедрять это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут можно попробовать решить вашу проблему с помощью кастомных путей до Remote Catalog Path. То есть попробовать генерировать несколько этих каталогов и грузить в игру в зависимости от надобности конкретного игрока. Очень сомневаюсь, что найдется игрок, у которого будут все несколько тысяч dlc объектов.

Сделать кастомный путь можно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем в настройках AddressableAssetSettings в поле Load Path значение . Тогда появляется возможность указать этот путь строкой. И вот тут есть небольшая хитрость - в этот путь можно вставлять константы, которые будут оцениваться либо во время сборки (Build Time), либо в во время выполнения (Runtime). 
Это делается несложно:

- указываем значение внутри {} скобок для Runtime переменных
- указываем значение внутри [] скобок для Buildtime переменных

Чтобы пояснить как это работает, пример:
Я проверял такие фокусы с RemoteLoadPath. Указал следующее значение:

```
[BundlesBuildPath.BaseUrl][BundlesBuildPath.Platform]/[BundlesBuildPath.BuildNumber]
```

Где `BundlesBuildPath` это класс вида:

```
public static class BundlesBuildPath
{
    public static string BaseUrl;
    public static string Platform;
    public static string Version;
    public static string BuildNumber;
}
```

Соответственно, когда собирается билд и дело доходит до бандлов, Addressable только в этот момент начинает оценивать значение, которое передали в строку RemoteLoadPath. Оценивает его оно через С# Reflection, честно по шаблону ищет вхождение скобок ({}/[]) в строку, берет значение, разбивает по символу '.', то что слева считает классом, что справа - свойством/переменной класса (ищет публичные или статичные). Для скорости, все что находит так через рефлексию - внутри кэширует (по этому вычислять будет только 1 раз за сессию). Информацию достал непосредственно из исходников, проверял на продакшене.

С помощью того, что вы можете задавать путь до этих бандлов через переменные - вы сможете генерировать этот путь в Runtime и давать пользователю скачать такой каталог, который ему нужен.

Еще один вариант, на основе кастомного пути до каталога - руками скачивать огромный каталог, только в архивированном виде (если там что-то а ля yaml или json, то сожмется очень хорошо), а путь указывать уже до разархивированного локально каталога.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Звучит многообещающе. Я только не пойму, как в этом случае создавать много небольших каталогов, вместо одного большого. Из коробки я так понял этого нет? То есть, придется писать какой-то редакторный скрипт, который пройдет по ассетам и разобъёт их на каталоги по n ассетов? Хочу понять, правильно ли я думаю. Я видел, есть AddressablesAssetGroups, но это не про каталоги..

Comment: @earthQuake думаю, что да - придется пошаманить руками или сделать скрипт для редактора

Comment: И еще одно уточнение на счет кеширования. Правильно ли я понимаю, что все каталоги, бандлы, ассеты будут прозрачно кешироваться? То есть, чтобы оно(кеширование) работало, я ничего не изобретаю, а просто использую их API. И если я даже оффлайн, но хочу получить каталог, который уже был ранее загружен, то я просто точно так же его загружаю и он уже достается локально. await Addressables.LoadContentCatalogAsync(path).Task; Ну и с самими ассетами то же самое. Спрашиваю, потому что у них как-то размыто об этом сейчас написано.

Comment: @earthQuake если вы что-то скачали (бандл или каталог) по их внутренним механизмам, то там работает кэш юнити. То есть если условно недавно скачали - все будет лежать на девайсе офлайн. Но этот кэш периодически очищается по времени. То есть если вы бандл месяц не использовали - кэш скорее всего его удалит. Но при след. обращении, addressables выкачает его заново за вас